# split() function return a string which is NOT splitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, split

I want to split this string:

> 120,00 m²

into this:

> 120 m²

I try it with this code:

```
var test = jQuery('#wpsight-listing-details-3 .span4:nth-child(4) .listing-details-value').html();

var partsOfStr = test.split(',');

alert(partsOfStr);
```

The alert returns everytime the 'old' string (120,00 m²).

Can somebody helps me?

Thank you very much!

Comment: That's because `alert` calls the `toString` method of the alerted value when value is not a string. The `toString` of an array joins the array elements using `,` by calling `Array.prototype.join` method. Use `console.log` for debugging!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option that covers different numbers after the comma:

```
   var result= "120,00 m²".replace(/[,]\d+[ ]/,' ');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```js
var test = "120,00 m²";
var partsOfStr = test.split(',00').join('');

alert(partsOfStr);
```

Comment: Thank you it works.
Can you tell me more about the join() function?

Comment: [Read it : `.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method make string out of  the array with passed args.

Comment: Ah okay. partsOfStr is an array and join() combines all parts of the array into one string again?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a regular expression and replace,  `.replace(/,\d+ m²/, ' m²')`

like this:

```js
$('.test').text('120,00 m²'.replace(/,\d+ m²/, ' m²'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a= '120,0,000,000,00 m²'; a.replace(/[,]\d+/g,' ');
```